# Why is headOption faster

Tags: scala, optimization, queue

I made a change to some code and it got 4.5x faster. I'm wondering why. It used to be essentially:

```
def doThing(queue: Queue[(String, String)]): Queue[(String, String)] = queue match {
  case Queue((thing, stuff), _*) => doThing(queue.tail)
  case _ => queue
}
```

and I changed it to this to get a huge speed boost:

```
def doThing(queue: Queue[(String, String)]): Queue[(String, String)] = queue.headOption match {
  case Some((thing, stuff)) => doThing(queue.tail)
  case _ => queue
}
```

What does `_*` do and why is it so expensive compared to headOption?

Comment: Is this the mutable `Queue` or the immutable one?

Comment: What is your compiler version?

Comment: Scala version is 2.10.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess after running scalac with `-Xprint:all` is that at the end of *patmat* in the `queue match { case Queue((thing, stuff), _*) => doThing(queue.tail) }` example I see the following methods being called (edited for brevity):

```
val o9 = scala.collection.immutable.Queue.unapplySeq[(String, String)](x1);
if (o9.isEmpty.unary_!)
  if (o9.get.!=(null).&&(o9.get.lengthCompare(1).>=(0)))
    {
      val p2: (String, String) = o9.get.apply(0);
      val p3: Seq[(String, String)] = o9.get.drop(1);
```

So [`lengthCompare`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L86) compare the length of the collection in a possibly optimized way. For `Queue`, it creates an iterator and iterates one time. So that should be somewhat fast. On the other hand [`drop(1)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L126) also constructs an iterator, skips one element and adds the rest of the elements to the result queue, so that would be linear in the size of the collection.

The `headOption` example is more straightforward, it checks if the list is empty (two comparisons), and if not returns a `Some(head)`, which then just has its `_1` and `_2` assigned to `thing` and `stuff`. So no iterators are created and nothing linear in the length of the collection.

Comment: What is your compiler version? I'm using `2.10.1` and `2.11.0-M3` and there is no `p3`.

Comment: @senia, 2.10.0. Are you checking the *immutable* queue?

Comment: @senia, I see what you mean, I do see `o9.get.apply(0)` with a more recent version and no `drop`.

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9wkc0BLu). I guess it's an improvement in versions > `2.10.0`.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no significant difference between your code samples.

`case Queue((thing, stuff), _*)` is actually translated by compiler to call of `head` (`apply(0)`) method. You could use `scalac -Xprint:patmat` to investigate this:

```
<synthetic> val p2: (String, String) = o9.get.apply(0);
if (p2.ne(null))
  matchEnd6(doThing(queue.tail))
```

The cost of `head` and cost of `headOption` are almost the same.

Methods `head`, `tail` and `dequeue` could cause `reverce` on internal `List` of `Queue` (with cost `O(n)`). In both you code samples there will be at most 2 `reverce` calls.
You should use `dequeue` like this to get at most a single `reverce` call:

```
def doThing(queue: Queue[(String, String)]): Queue[(String, String)] =
  if (queue.isEmpty) queue
  else queue.dequeue match {
    case (e, q) => doThing(q)
  }
```

You could also replace `(thing, stuff)` with `_`. In this case compiler will generate only call of `lengthCompare` without `head` or `tail`:

```
if (o9.get != null && o9.get.lengthCompare(1) >= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that too. But why the discrepancy in my examples?

Comment: @kelloti: are you sure performance is not the same in both examples? Your code could be optimized as useless by jit. As I can see from `scalac -Xprint:patmat` there is no significant difference between your 2 code samples.

Comment: @senia, I don't think `head` and `tail` are O(n). See https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala#L81. It really leverages structural sharing and it seems O(1) to me. Sorry I take the O(1) back, there is a `in.reverse` in there. But that is also true of `dequeue`.

Comment: You are correct, it's `O(1)`. I can see the only option: your benchmark is not correct.

Comment: There will be at most 2 `in.reverse` in your examples, and 1 with `dequeue`. It's not a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

`_*` is used to specify varargs arguments, so what you are doing in the first version is deconstructing the Queue into a pair of Strings, and an appropriate number of further pairs of Strings - ie you are deconstructing the whole Queue even though you only care about the first element.

If you just remove the asterisk, giving

```
def doThing(queue: Queue[(String, String)]): Queue[(String, String)] = queue match {
  case Queue((thing, stuff), _) => doThing(queue.tail)
  case _ => queue
}
```

then you are only deconstructing the Queue into a pair of Strings, and a remainder (which thus does not need to be fully deconstructed). This should run in comparable time to your second version (haven't timed it myself, though).

Comment: `Queue((thing, stuff), _)` is a pattern for collection of **2** elements.

Comment: @senia Oops, you're right - I was thinking Queue was constructed like List. Nevertheless, the deconstruction argument around why `_*` takes so long would still apply (but stick with using headOption or dequeue or similar for the method).

Comment: `Queue` is actually constructed using 2 lists. But `List(a, b)` is also a pattern for list of 2 elements.